# Does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}f_{n}\left(x\right) $ converge a.e over $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of integrable functions in $\left(X,\mathcal{M},\mu\right)
 $. Assume that $\int_{X}\left|f_{n}\right|d\mu\leq1$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}f_{n}\left(x\right)$ converge a.e over $X$?

I have no idea. Help me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $g_N(x):=\sum_{n=1}^N2^{-n}|f_n(x)|$. Then $g_N\to g$ almost everywhere, where $g=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}|f_n(x)|$. The assumption on the $f_n$ and monotone convergence theorem show that $g$ is integrable, hence finite almost everywhere.